# Change default disk controller in Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have some network-booted (PXE/TFTP) test/dev vms that are created and run using  Vagrant.

However, by default Vagrant/Virtualbox adds SATA controller while some of those vms run older Linux distros that do not understand SATA and require virtual IDE controllers.

I can't seem to find the way to *change* controller type in Virtualbox that I could  [customize in Vagrant](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/customize.html).

Is there a way to specify disk controller type in Vagrant (or, not so preferably, in underlying Virtualbox itself) using smth like http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storagectl ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact commands for `VBoxManage`, you could try something like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # ...

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--remove"]
    v.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "IDE Controller", "--add", ...]
  end

end
```

Comment: I suppose your ellipses are for VBoxManage commands, but I was just trying to add an IDE Controller and got an "--add expects an argument" error until I replaced the ellipses with "ide". Then it worked.